# Error if lib fetched from Bintray repo but not when fetched from Jcenter

Tags: android, maven, pom.xml, bintray, jcenter

I make android libraries and I noticed that when I fetch the package from my maven repository on Bintray account, an error occurs.

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve net.mysite.lib_package:version
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve net.mysite.lib_package:version

The way I add my repo to Gradle is:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://bintray.com/myusername/myrepo/"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem does not show up when I fetch from Jcenter. I checked other libraries of mine and other random libraries as well and the problem occurs only when fetching from user's Bintray Maven repo.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is incorrect. You should use the `https://dl.bintray.com/[YOUR_USERNAME]/<REPOSITORY_NAME>`.

Example:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/myusername/myrepo/"
    }
  }
}
```

Check this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Maven+Repositories) for Maven Repositories & Resolving Artifacts.